# Tapping on approved suggested tag wiki leads to 404 in iOS-app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, tag-wiki

Recently my suggested edit on tag wiki has been approved. In app I see a reputation change on it, but when I tap on it I got "page not found":

> [image: ios]

Open in Chrome opens [an actual page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651387) for tag wiki:

> [image: chrome]

- App Version: 1.6.5.1
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Working on a fix.  Glass half full kind of thing though, tag wiki approvals are now appearing in achievements.  That's a long-standing feature request.  Basically, the problem is that achievements is returning `/q/{id}`, instead of `/tags/{name}/info` and the app has no way of handling non-question-or-answer `/q/` links.  We need the API to return the resolved link instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed.

The problem was that the links returned from the achievements were `/q/{postId}` instead of `/tags/{tagName}/info`.  The app and the API have no real way of non-question/answer post ids, resulting in the bad 404 page.

I fixed this by removing code that overwrote the already present `/tags/{tagName}/info` link.  Unfortunately, this uncovered a different bug where tag wikis for posts failed to resolve when the tag wiki was on another site (e.g., your tag wiki achievement on ru.so wouldn't appear when on mse).  Nick fixed that though.

Links like https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651387 will still fail in the app, but they should be uncommon now.

Comment: Thanks for fix. But why I [can't see tag excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukdYc.jpg)?